# alternative to mysql_nd functions

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

I moved my php code to a new hosting which missing `mysql_nd` and a have more than 150 functions that use `stmt->get_result()` and `fetch_assoc`.

Is there a function that can do the same work of `stmt->get_result()` and `fetch_assoc` and give the exact results so I can fix the problem without having to modify all the functions?

Comment: `mysql_*` functions were deprecated in php5 and removed in php7 - switch to pdo

Comment: Are you saying you downgraded your PHP version? Why? I would stay away from such hosting.

Comment: Note that [`mysqlnd`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) is not the same as `mysql`. If the server does not have PHP compiled with `mysqlnd` and the hosting server won't install it for you, then you'll have to either deal with the existing non-mysqlnd functions, or switch to PDO.  However, I think you should be able to use `fetch_assoc` even without `get_result`

Comment: What kind of functions do you have for getting results using `mysqlnd` ? I always thought that `mysqlnd` was at a lower level than `mysqli`

Comment: @apokryfos I'm getting the error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result

Comment: Update to a proper PHP version and you won't have this problem.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#113398 has a solution for that

Comment: @apokryfos Yikes! This comment was posted 5 years ago. There should be no reason to use such nasty solutions anymore.

Comment: @Dharman I am using php 7.2 in the old and new hosting

Comment: You need to ask your hosting provider then, because something must be misconfigured on your server.

Answer (score -1):

You have two choices.
The first is to contact your provider indicating that you need MySql Native Driver.
The second is to review all your code as a PDO or alternatively MySqli (PDO Council).
In terms of time, with the second option we invest a little more, but for sure you will make your application more stable and secure. I would personally use it for the second hypothesis.